# What is the prototype of a Function object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

I have just written this snippet of code.

```
 function Point(x,y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    var myPoint = new Point(4,5);
    console.log(myPoint.__proto__ === Point.prototype);
    console.log(Point.__proto__ === Function.prototype);
    console.log(Function.__proto__ === Object.prototype);
```

The first two expressions returns true but the 3rd expression returns false.I am not sure why it returns false, because as per the below image, it is supposed to return true.
[image: Inheritance]

In the image you can notice Function.prototype's __ *proto* __ property point to Object.prototype.

Could anyone please clear my concepts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In the image you can notice Function.prototype's __ proto __ property point to Object.prototype.

But that is not what you tested! You tested `Function.__proto__`, which is actually equal to `Function.prototype`. Try this instead:

```
console.log(Function.prototype.__proto__ === Object.prototype);
```

Comment: Maybe also note that the prototype of `Function` is actually the `Empty` function.

Comment: You are correct. But what does this would return console.log(Function.__proto__); As function is also a predefined Object in jS.

Comment: Ah, now I understand your question... [Function is actually a predefined constructor function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function), not a predefined object. You can call `new Function()` similarly to how you can call `new Point()` and `new Object()`